# "Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop."

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I came across this error int he console. I had a look through the previous questions but they were not much help. Anyone know how I have caused this infinite loop?

"Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop."

```js
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Movie from './components/Movie'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

  const FEATURED_API = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=04c35731a5ee918f014970082a0088b1&page=1"
  const IMG_API = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280"
  const SEARCH_API = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?&api_key=04c35731a5ee918f014970082a0088b1&query="


  function App() {
    const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
      fetch(FEATURED_API)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) =>  {
        console.log(data)
        setMovies(data.results);
      });
    },[])
    setMovies(movies)
  

    return <div>{ movies.length > 0 && movies.map((movie) =>  <Movie/>)}</div>
    
}
export default App;
```

Comment: `setMovies(movies)` should not be there I would think.

Answer (score 2):

You can't set states outside functions or hooks in components.

Just remove the `setMovies(movies)` and it should work ;)

Comment: I am an idiot. Thankyou very much! :) Worked a charm

Comment: it happens even to the best, no problem mate ;)

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the `setMovies` function queues a re-render that will take place as soon as the component has finished rendering. Given this behavior, if the `setMovies` function is placed outside of a function or a `useEffect`, it will get you stuck in a loop!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).